# SQL Inner join with case when

Tags: sql

I need help to manage one query to be functionality.
Need to pass few inner joins and after that to be compared some values and based on that to update status with correct letter.

```
update t_carton_box 
set status =  (select * 
                from t_entries e 
                inner join t_aql a 
                    on e.aql_id = a.aql_id  
                inner join t_aql_ver av 
                    on av.id=a.aql_ver_id   
                inner join t_carton_box c 
                    on e.carton_box = c.carton_box  
                inner join t_entries ee 
                    on case 
                        when sum(ee.reject) < a.reject 
                                then 'A' 
                        else 'R' end )
```

I tried with code above but doesn't work :(

Sorry for bad description. I have table t_carton_box with columns, one of them is status. That status for all records need to be updated with letter 'A' or 'R'. Which letter will be depends if sum(t_entries.rejecte) < t_aql.reject . Also must other inner joins included, because that condition will give me correct value t_aql.reject –

Update:

t_entries has columns entry_id, accept,reject,carton_box,fk_aql_id t_aql has columns aql_id,accept,reject, fk_aql_ver_id t_aql_ver has columns id,name t_carton box has columns carton_box_id, carton_box, status Table t_entries can containt multiple records with same carton_box and columns accept and reject are int. I need to get sum of reject from t_entries for carton_box and check is greater from t_aql. If is greater for that carton_box in table t_carton_box will be updated status with 'R' else 'A'. I hope know it more clear for you.

Comment: `doesn't work` is not enough information

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results, along with an explanation of the logic.  The use of `sum()` in the `on` clause is not valid SQL and doesn't explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: I think the `on case when sum(...)` is completely nonsense. You can't use `case when` with an output in a join

Comment: please tell us which rdbms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not work because you are trying to update one column with multiple values. 
i.e. status is one column while * will give you multiple columns.

```
set status =  (select *
```

Based on OP's edit, SQL will be :

```
UPDATE TCB
SET TCB.STATUS = TE_SUM_O.STATUS
FROM T_CARTON_BOX TCB
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT TE_SUM.CARTON_BOX,(CASE WHEN TE_SUM.REJECT=TE_SUM.TE_REJECT THEN 'R' ELSE 'A' END)STATUS
            FROM(
            SELECT TE.CARTON_BOX,TA.REJECT,SUM(TE.REJECT)TE_REJECT
            FROM T_AQL TA
            INNER JOIN T_ENTRIES TE
            ON TA.AQL_ID = TE.FK_AQL_ID
            GROUP BY TE.CARTON_BOX,TA.REJECT)TE_SUM
            )TE_SUM_O
ON TCB.CARTON_BOX=TE_SUM_O.CARTON_BOX
```

Comment: Ok, I figure that. But how should I return letter A or R ?

Comment: @danijel I want to help you. but can you please provide more information? like sample data from all table and desired output etc.?

Comment: t_entries has columns entry_id, accept,reject,carton_box,fk_aql_id
t_aql has columns aql_id,accept,reject, fk_aql_ver_id
t_aql_ver has columns id,name
t_carton box has columns carton_box_id, carton_box, status

Table t_entries can containt multiple records with same carton_box and columns accept and reject are int. I need to get sum of reject from t_entries for carton_box  and check is greater from t_aql. If is greater for that carton_box in table t_carton_box will be updated status with 'R' else 'A'. I hope know it more clear for you.

Comment: Yes. It is more clear now. Can you please paste same information in your original post? You can edit it. So more people will able to help  you.

Comment: @DanijelBoksan please check my answer above. Let me know if you need any more help.

Answer (score 0):

a subselect returning * is never working with equal comparison '='